# Post item of IEnumaration to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble figuring out what is the best aproach to a rather simple problem.

I have a payment view-model that contains a list of avalible payments and some base properties like title, content...

So in my view I use `@using(Html.BeginForm())` and inside that I loop over the payments and render each out and of course the view-model that I recive in my controller post has and empty list of payment methods.

I can see that if I use a `for` and print out `model.paymentMethods[i].Prop` than it can map it but is this the right aproach or can I do something even smarter?

Comment: Or would it be better to go after a controller post that only took end id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the model-binder to work you need to use indexed access.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PaymentMethods)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => item.Prop);
}
```

does **NOT** work.

You need to use:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < m.PaymentMethods.Count(), ++i)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PaymentMethods[i].Prop);
}
```

Otherwise the model-binder can't map it back in the post-back.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can create a editor template of **Payment** type. And in view you can use that editor template like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PaymentMethods)
```